# I have a language where I need to determine if my flow control statement predicates are tautologies or contradictions

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-errors, boolean-expression

Hello I'm working on a domain specific language with my project group.
We want to report to the language user if the predicate in for example if(predicate) or while(predicate) are always true or always false. The logic operators implemented on the language are AND, OR, NEGATION as well as the comparison operators, <,>, >=, <=, !=, =(equal).

I naturally only want to examine predicates with literals symbols such as false, true, numbers, and strings. Evaluating the values symbols of the expressions is no problem.

Are all these things possible and are they existing information I can look at to achieve this maybe even some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restrict your formulas to Boolean logic over predicate leaves (e.g., you treat the relational comparisons at "ground literals"), you can verify if a formula is a tautology or not by applying Wang's rules of inference, here captured in a algebraic specification where the axioms can be treated as left-to-right rewrite rules:

```
WANG =
{   sort Boolean;

    true, false: Boolean;

    Boolean generated by true, false;

    not: Boolean ® Boolean;
    and, or: Boolean --> Boolean ® Boolean
               associative commutative;
    implies, equivalent: Boolean --> Boolean ® Boolean;

    axioms
    -- 3 simplification rules for not
        «not1»  not(true) = false;
        «not2»  not(false) = true;
        «not3»  not(not(x)) = x;
    -- definition of 'implies'
        «impl»  implies(x,y) = or(not(x),y);
    -- definition of 'and'
        «and»  and(x,y) = not(or(not(x),not(y)));
    -- definition of 'equivalent'
        «eq»    equivalent(x,y) = and(implies(x,y),implies(y,x));
    -- simplification rules for 'or'
        «or01»  or(true,x) = true;
        «or02»  or(false,x) = x;
        «or03»  or(x,not(x)) = true;
        «or04»  or(x,or(not(x),y)) = true;
        «or05»  or(x,x) = x;
        «or06»  or(x,or(x,y)) = or(x,y);
        «or07»  or(not(or(x,y)),x) = or(x,not(y));
        «or08»  or(not(or(x,y)),or(x,z)) = or(x,or(not(y),z));
        «or09»  or(not(or(x,y)),not(x)) = not(x);
        «or10»  or(not(or(x,y)),or(not(x),z)) = or(not(x),z);
        «or11»  or(not(or(not(x),y)),x) = x;
        «or12»  or(not(or(not(x),y)),or(x,z)) = or(x,z);
        «or13»  or(not(or(not(x),y)),not(or(x,y))) = not(y);
        «or14»  or(not(or(not(x),y)),or(not(or(x,y)),z)) = or(not(y),z);
 endaxioms;
}
```

The beauty of these rewrite rules is that you can apply them in any order to a boolean equation.  Eventually, no rules will further apply.  At that point, your formula is either TRUE (a tautology),  FALSE (an anti-tautology), or something else (neither TRUE or FALSE).

(This particular rule set was applied directly by DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit.  You can implement your own "rewriter" by build (abstract) syntax trees for your Boolean expression, and then implementing all these rules as relatively simple  procedures that walk over the tree looking for a place they might apply, and simply apply them when such a place is found.  This is actually pretty straightforward.).

Comment: I'm sure this ruleset does not solve the SAT problem which is even a subset of what's being asked here. You seem to claim that is solves SAT because this (allegedly) can answer the question "is there an assignment for the ground literals such that the resulting formula is true". That's SAT.

Comment: I do not claim it solves the SAT problem.   It solves the problem of determining if the boolean proposition is a tautology, which is what OP asked.

Comment: Determining that *is* solving the SAT problem. If p(x) is UNSAT then !p(x) is a tautology. So you can determine whether p(x) or !p(x) is a tautology and you know whether the problem is SAT or UNSAT.

Comment: I'm going to ignore the discussion about SAT as a red herring.  The only relevant question for OP is, "is this a decision  procedure for determining if a boolean equation is a tautology?"   I claim it is, and I make that claim based on paper by a "Dr. Wang" from the 1930s(?), in which he published this result.   I cannot find the reference to this paper online; my memory of this is from the 80s, and we have used this in production tools.   There is a discussion about decision procedures based on rewriting boolean equations involving another Wang; I'm sure it is different.  I will keep looking.

Comment: In the meantime, here is a reference to the modern Wang paper: "Towards Feasible Solutions of the Tautology Problem, Dunham and Wang, Annals of Mathematical Logic 1976.  PDF: http://ac.els-cdn.com/0003484376900206/1-s2.0-0003484376900206-main.pdf?_tid=980b1036-ee00-11e4-9bc0-00000aacb360&acdnat=1430264884_1c2875f44317bf78944a24687e9f797c

Comment: I'm with Ira here, although I think the proof might be non-trivial. A simpler and roughly equivalent algorithm would be mechanically reducing the expression to either disjunctive or conjunctive normal form, and then factoring using DeMorgan's law. SAT is not actually a terribly difficult problem unless you want to solve it in less than exponential time; however, in most computer programs, conditional expressions in `if` and `while` statements do not have enough terms to make a simple exponential algorithm impractical.

Comment: If you check out the rewrites as posted, what they do is normalize away "and" "eqv" "imp" leaving just "nots" and "or". The rules for simplifying the or terms is where the magic happens.  No, I don't have the proof and I agree it might be complex; that's why Dr. Wang published his paper :-}  But you can see the "or" rules read left-to-right strictly decrease term size, so it is clear it terminates. The whole reason I glommed onto this set of rules back in the 80s is because it is blindingly simple to build a tautology detector with this. (No, there's no guarantee it is lightning fast).

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments ill update the origin post with the solution when I eventually get around to implementing it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the control flow is free of loops (and free of gotos and recusion; anything that can be used to simulate an unbounded loop) this is possible. You can use an SMT solver to solve pretty much arbitrary formulas and tell you whether a certain boolean expression is always true or false. The run time of that SMT solver might be impractical. Some SMT solvers are not complete, either. They sometimes answer "unknown". Look into Z3. It is free and of very high quality and performance.

If arbitrary control flow is involved (if this is a turing-complete language) then the Halting Problem says that you cannot solve this problem in general. You will have to make due with heuristics.

I think your approach should not be part of the language design. Make this a static analysis tool that is allowed to sometimes answer "I don't know".

Comment: By free of loops do you mean that you cannot do this check inside of scope which is a unbounded loop or even in scopes which has a possible unbounded loop(we only have while loops)? Z3 sounds like exactly what we need, thanks.

Comment: There is a thing called the Goldbach Conjecture which is unproven. Can your language check that conjecture (any turing complete language can)? If yes then in all likelyhood you cannot answer all SMT queries. This is a good litmus test. The SMT solver is not better than all human researchers who have tried this conjecture. If you ask the solver "Is the conjecture true?" it will say "unknown".